# Refactoring a Zend_View_Helper_Action widget, utilizing Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger, into a model

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db-table

I've tried to create a login widget that can be included at will in any action that is outside the content of the application that requires login. My thought here was that I wanted a DRY-approach for rendering the login box with any error messages from a previous login attempt. To enable this I utilized the [FlashMessenger](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.flashmessenger) for saving the result of a failed login-attempt. The widget also uses the [Post/Redirect/Get-pattern](http://www.theserverside.com/patterns/thread.tss?thread_id=20936) to avoid the problem of posting data multiple times when using the browser back-button.

Now, the problem is that I would rather not use the [Zend_View_Helper_Action](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.action) since that helper clones the request and creates another run of the dispatch-loop, which is pretty resource intensive. So, by looking at the code below, could you give me some advice on how to refactor the code such that:

1. **The widget can be included in an arbitrary view script**
2. **Results from a previous login attempt is rendered**
3. **The widget does not invoke a run in the dispatch-loop**

Currently, the login widget is rendered by calling, in the view scripts:

```
echo $this->action('auth', 'login-widget');
```

AuthController.php:

```
class AuthController extends Zend_Controller_Action {    
    // This method is invoked by Zend_View_Helper_Action to render the
    // login widget
    public function loginWidgetAction () {
        $flashMessenger = $this->_helper->flashMessenger->setNamespace('login');
        $this->view->messages = $flashMessenger->getMessages();
    }

    public function loginAction () {
        if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $result = Auth::doLogin($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            if($result->isValid()) {
                $this->_redirect('user');
            } 
            else {
                $flashMessenger = $this->_helper->flashMessenger->
                                                  setNamespace('login');
                foreach($result->getMessages() as $message) {
                    $flashMessenger->addMessage($message);    
                }
            }
        }
        // This will be changed to redirect either to the index page,
        // or the page the request originated from if available.
        $this->_redirect('');
    }
    [...]
}
```

/models/Auth.php:

```
/**
 * Model for encapsulating the actions that deals with authentication,
 * such as registering and activating users, as well as logging in and
 * logging out.
 * @todo: Refactor this to remove static methods
 */
class Auth {

    /**
     * 
     * @return Zend_Auth_Result
     */
    public static function doLogin ($credentials) {
        $authAdapter = new Auth_Adapter_DbTable(
            Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter(),
            'Users',
            'username',
            'pwdHash',
            'SHA1(CONCAT(?, salt))'
        );
        $authAdapter->setIdentity($credentials['username']);
        $authAdapter->setCredential($credentials['password']);
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        return $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);
}
[...]
}
```

/models/Auth/Adapter/DbTable.php:

```
class Auth_Adapter_DbTable extends Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable {    

    /**
     * authenticate() - defined by Zend_Auth_Adapter_Interface.  This method 
     * is called to attempt an authenication.  Previous to this call, this
     * adapter would have already been configured with all necessary 
     * information to successfully connect to a database table and attempt
     * to find a record matching the provided identity.
     *
     * @throws Zend_Auth_Adapter_Exception if answering the authentication 
     * query is impossible
     * @see library/Zend/Auth/Adapter/Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable#authenticate()
     * @return MedU_Auth_Result
     */
    public function authenticate() {
        return parent::authenticate();
    }

    /**
     * _authenticateValidateResult() - This method attempts to validate that
     * the record in the result set is indeed a record that matched the 
     * identity provided to this adapter.
     * 
     * Additionally it checks that the user account is activated. 
     *
     * @param array $resultIdentity
     * @return MedU_Auth_Result
     */
    protected function _authenticateValidateResult($resultIdentity)
    {
        $result = parent::_authenticateValidateResult($resultIdentity);
        if(!$result->isValid()) { return $result; }

        $this->_checkAccountIsActivated($resultIdentity);
        $this->_checkAccountIsSuspended($resultIdentity);

        // Overwrite the username supplied by the user and instead
        // use the name supplied upon registration, i.e if the
        // user signs in as uSERNAME and registered as Username,
        // the identity is Username
        $this->_authenticateResultInfo['identity'] = 
            $resultIdentity[$this->_identityColumn]; 

        return $this->_authenticateCreateAuthResult();
    }

    protected function _checkAccountIsActivated ($resultIdentity) {
        if(!$resultIdentity['activated']) {
            $this->_authenticateResultInfo['code'] = 
                MedU_Auth_Result::FAILURE_NOT_ACTIVATED;
            $this->_authenticateResultInfo['messages'] = 
                array('The account has not yet been activated. 
                       Please click on the link provided in the 
                       activation email.');
        }
    }

    protected function _checkAccountIsSuspended ($resultIdentity) {
        if($resultIdentity['suspended']) {
            $this->_authenticateResultInfo['code'] = 
                MedU_Auth_Result::FAILURE_SUSPENDED;
            $this->_authenticateResultInfo['messages'] = 
                  array('The account has been suspended. 
                         If you feel this is a mistake, 
                         please contact our support: support@meduniverse.com');
        }
    }

    /**
     * _authenticateCreateAuthResult() - This method creates a 
     * MedU_Auth_Result object from the information that has 
     * been collected during the authenticate() attempt.
     *
     * @return MedU_Auth_Result
     */
    protected function _authenticateCreateAuthResult()
    {
        return new MedU_Auth_Result(
            $this->_authenticateResultInfo['code'],
            $this->_authenticateResultInfo['identity'],
            $this->_authenticateResultInfo['messages']
           );
    }
}
```

/views/scripts/auth/partials/login-widget.phtml

```
// The fetchForm-view helper returns a Zend_Form object. 
// The form definition (xml) is attached below in the
// code box below this one.
<div class="box">
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <?php if($this->messages) : ?>
            <ul class="errors">
                <?php foreach($this->messages as $message) : ?>
                    <li><?php echo $message ?></li>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div>
        <?php echo $this->fetchForm('user', 'login') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

/application/configs/forms.xml

```
// Configuration of the Login form. 'user' and 'login' are 
// just keys for the view helper to return the correct form
<forms>
    <user>
        <login>
            <action value="/auth/login" />
            <method value="post" />
            <elements>
                <username>
                    <type value="text"></type>
                    <options>
                        <label value="Username" />
                        <required value="true" />
                        <validators>
                            <alnum validator="alnum" />
                            <strlen validator="StringLength">
                                <options min="6" max="45" />
                            </strlen>
                        </validators>
                    </options>
                </username>

                <password>
                    <type value="password" />
                    <options>
                        <label value="Password" />
                        <required value="true" />
                        <validators>
                            <strlen validator="StringLength">
                                <options min="6" max="20" />
                            </strlen>
                        </validators>
                    </options>
                </password>

                <submit>
                    <type value="submit" />
                    <options>
                        <label value="Log in" />
                    </options>
                </submit>
            </elements>
    </login>
```

Comment: +1, Interesting question, but why would you not issue a simple redirect to, say, AuthController->loginAction when a non logged-in user tries to access protected content? Is there a special reason?

Comment: Sure, I will still have to do that, but I'd like to be able to give the user the ability to log in when he feels like it, without forcing him to first click a link that requires login. For instance, to have a login-box in a side-bar when the user isn't logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your solution, your current call to the `Zend_View_Helper_Action` helper does nothing more than rendering the login form. Why don't you write your on view helper that retrieves the login-related messages from the flash-messenger and renders the login form?

**EDIT:**

1. You can retrieve the flash-messenger from its static broker:

   ```
   $flashMessenger = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('FlashMessenger');
   $flashMessenger->setNamespace('login');
   $messages = $flashMessenger->getMessages();
   ```
2. You don't need to instatiate a new flash-messenger in your view helper, you just can retrieve the current instance of it (see 1.). From a design point of view I'd say that it's absolutely feasible to retrieve application components within your view helpers (the `Zend_View_Helper_Url` for example retrieves the router from the static front-controller). To reduce coupling and to implement a setter-dependency-injection-pattern I'd suggest the following (`Zend_View_Helper_Translate` uses a similar pattern to retrieve the translator):

   ```
   class My_View_Helper_Login extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
   {
       // [...]
       /**
        * @var Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger
        */
       protected $_flash;
       /**
        * @param Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger $flash
        * @return My_View_Helper_Login Provides a fluent interface
        */
       public function setFlashMessenger(Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger $flash)
       {
           $this->_flash = $flash;
           return $this;
       }
       /**
        * @return Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger
        */
       public function getFlashMessenger()
       {
           if ($this->_flash === null) {
               $this->_flash = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('FlashMessenger');
           }
           return $this->_flash;
       }
       /**
        *
        */
       public function login()
       {
           $flashMessenger = $this->getFlashMessenger();
           $flashMessenger->setNamespace('login');
           $messages = $flashMessenger->getMessages();
           // [...]
        }
   }
   ```
3. Not when the flash-messenger provides the functionality you need. If you need to distinguish between error, informational and success messages for example a home-grown solution would perhaps be the better way.

Comment: It does a little more than that. It also fetches the error messages and pushes them into the view. I thought of using a view-helper instead of a controller action, but I hesitated on these points:

* Is it correct to instantiate a Zend_Controller_Action_Helper in a view helper? (The FlashMessenger).

* How do I instantiate it in a proper way?

* Should I build my own error passing mechanism instead of utilizing the flash messenger?

Comment: I think you forgot either a ! or empty($this->_flash) in getFlashMessenger. Other than that, this solution works just as well as using the action view helper. I like your idea of a dependency injector pattern, even though it might be overkill in this scenario. Thanks for your help and ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Another addition is that you can use FlashMessenger to store *ANY* data. So you can do

```
$flash->addMessage(array('status'=>'error','message'=> 'oops'));
```

and then in foreach use

```
foreach($messages as $message){
echo '<div class="message '. $message['status'] .'">' . $message['message'] . '</div>'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use ViewHelper to render form and ActionController for authentication?
This frees you from second dispatch-loop.
I can show you some little example, if you want.

P.S. You sure need validators for form? I don`t see any use in your example.

Comment: I probably don't need any validators, and I don't use them at the moment. I just added them in while configuring the form, but you're right. I should probably take them out if I find no use for them.